# Passing multi-dimensional array to function with **ptr

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Just today I was thinking about different ways to pass multi-dimensional arrays to functions. The methods I know summarized in three little functions:

```
void method_a(int m, int n, int (*ptr_arr)[n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
         for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         {
            ptr_arr[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
}

void method_c(int m, int n, int arr[][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = j + 3;
        }
    }
}

void method_b(int m, int n, int *ptr_arr)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            *((ptr_arr + i * n) + j) = j + 2;
        }


}
```

I have also read the claim a lot that the following is equivalent to `method_a()`:

```
void method_d(int m, int n, int **ptr_arr)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
         for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
         {
            ptr_arr[i][j] = j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not seem to work with static arrays. Does this only work with dynamically allocated arrays via `malloc()`. If it does also work with statically declared arrays could someone give an example?

Comment: Wherever you read that claim, it's wrong. `method_a` and `method_c` are equivalent (declaration, anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods a, b, and c are equivalent and application to bidimensional arrays (declared as `int arr[x][y]`). Method d is applicable to a totally different object : an array of pointers to unidimensional arrays.

Bidi array :

a<sub>00</sub> a<sub>01</sub> a<sub>02</sub> a<sub>03</sub>

a<sub>10</sub> a<sub>11</sub> a<sub>12</sub> a<sub>13</sub>

a<sub>20</sub> a<sub>21</sub> a<sub>22</sub> a<sub>23</sub>

Array of pointers

```
a0 a1 a2

|  |  |________ a20 a21 a22 a23
|  |___________ a10 a11 a12 a13
|______________ a00 a01 a02 a03
```

In that case, you have an array of pointers pointing to the different rows, and the rows need not be consecutive in memory

Or if you have a bidimensional array, say `int arr[3][4];`, you can easily build an array of pointers using it :

```
int *ptarr[3];
...
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    ptarr[i] = &(arr[i][0]);
}
```

you can then use it with your method d

Comment: Thank you! I knew about flattened arrays but I was confused regarding `method_d()` because in the previous `method_b()`, using a single pointer, I also thought I have a flattened array because I cannot use `ptr_arr[i][j]` to index the matrix but rather have to specify the offset to the right.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no because `int **` and `int *[N]` are different types.

You need to understand what are the types of variables you are working on. Many people confuse matrices declared in a contiguous memory region with arrays of pointers. IMHO this is because the syntax `matrix[a][b]` is identical for both approaches.

However, `int **mat1` is not an equivalent to `int mat2[][N]`. `mat2` is an array of `int[N]` arrays. `mat1` is something less - just a pointer to a pointer to an integer. You don't know how many are there.

If you have matrix declared in a contiguous memory region (`mat2`), to properly compute the place of the element, you need to know dimensions, except the first. This is because you need to know how many "frames" (`int[N]`s in case of `mat2`) you need to skip when changing index, and the last one given by type. E.g. if you have `int mat[4][5]`, to change from `[1][3]` to `[2][3]` you need to know, that there is `6` integers in a row. But going from `[1][3]` to `[1][4]` is just one `int`, so size this dimension is not needed. This is also the reason why any matrix can *decay* to a pointer of appropriate type of one less dimension, but only one less!

In `method_a` you have this information (its in the type naturally). If you have pointer to a pointer `mat[x][y]` is treated differently. It works like this:

```
int element;
int *row;
row = mat[x];
element = row[y];
```

Note that there are two indirections! You cannot compute element position immediately from `x` and `y`. Elements of consecutive rows do not have to lay next to each other. Only the pointers to them do. They also don't have to be of the same length.

This is why there are errors when passing static multidimensional arrays as pointer-to-a-pointer style ones.

Comment: Not coincidentally, the same syntax will also work for `int (*mat)[N]` and `int mat[][N]` (which are actually the same anyway), thereby questioning whether that is a stellar example of how things are "different".

Comment: Yea, but it was meant only to show how it works. I know the syntax works for both types because of decay. The point was, you cannot do it differently (i.e. just compute the elements position) in case of pointer-to-a-pointer. I am not sure... is it confusing?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think that WhozCraig meant, that the code example I gave, to depict how does `mat[x][y]` works for `T** mat`, will actually work for `T mat[][N]` too. And it does, because of decay. Those are what I meant by two types.

Comment: @luk32 OK fair enough

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well, it probably does indicate, that I failed at explaining things and expressing myself clearly in my answer =). Well, maybe someone someday will get it and find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that last method is that the compiler has no way to figure out how large a row of the array is, since you just have a pointer to a pointer to an int, rather than a pointer to an array.

If you look at your third method (the one labeled method_b), you are doing this manually for the compiler when you multiply i * n before adding j.  In method_a and method_b, you are providing the value of 'n' in the function prototype.

In the "method_d" code, the compiler doesn't have any way to figure out what the value of 'n' is, so it can't calculate an array offset from ptr_arr[i][j].